# Change browser title in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, tab, browser

I want to change the default browser title when the user press my Lightning Component Tab. How can I do it?

In visualforce, I had the title attribute `<apex:page title="My title">`, but in Lightning Experience I found no way to accomplish this, the title is always *Lightning Experience | Salesforce*:

[image: Browser title]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do that in `init` handler of component.

Sample:

cmp file:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="GLOBAL">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

</aura:component>
```

controller JS:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        document.title = "My Custom Component";
    }
});
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I fixed: I preferred to avoid this because of the locker service, but then I found that the title attribute is allowed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer. However, I did it in the Renderer file because I experienced that the title is not replaced upon tab changes if I just use the init event (eg: try to navigate to another component and back).

Comment: For navigation, you should be using pageReference Object. You should be handling it using change handler on pageReference object and not renderer. Renderer runs for every `component.set` - will have adverse effects on performance

Comment: I mean standard navigation, changing salesforce tab and back, not "custom navigation" (with page references etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the title in the initialization of your controller...

e.g. `document.title = "Test"`

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute in `<apex:page>` will set the title of the window ([since Summer '16](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/download/file/0693A000005baZjQAI)).

To update the browser window title from a Visualforce page in Lightning Experience, you can send a message to the parent window:

```
window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"event":"force:setTitle","arguments":{"title": "NEW TITLE"}}) , window.location.ancestorOrigins[0]);
```