# set browser tab name lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC that runs inside a custom SF tab, I want to know how to change the browser tab name ?

I only managed to find [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274407/change-browser-title-in-lightning-experience) answer but it is for aura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.title` still works fine, the issue is it gets overriden by the record name if the lwc component is on a record page, rest for an app page it works fine.

So you can try giving it a timeout if its a record page.

```
connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(function (){
        document.title = 'Test Me Please';
    },10000);
}
```

Or just try by removing the settimout if its a app page:

```
connectedCallback() {
        document.title = 'Test Me Please';    
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to use "setTimeout" in a LWC though. I'd say it is not worth the effort to rename the tab at all.

Comment: Why is it not possible to use settimeout in lwc? Any reason?

Comment: It is explained in this other Q&A: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261416/restricted-async-operation-settimeout-in-lwc

Comment: Its just a `es-lint` plugin which gives a warning. Though from LWC its not restricted, though for above scenario as its a custom app, I think there is not need of `setTimeout`

Comment: Hi @NagendraSingh, document.title did the trick (without setTimeout), thank you.

Comment: You are right, I swear I thought it was a restriction... so sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It's now possible to update the **console tab** name (& icon) from the LWC itself

I did the following having a custom tab displaying a LWC.

You need to import the following functions from the platform workspace API in your LWC js controller

```
import { setTabLabel, getFocusedTabInfo, setTabIcon } from "lightning/platformWorkspaceApi";
```

And then, for example, in the connectedCallBack

```
connectedCallback() {
    getFocusedTabInfo().then((tabInfo) => {
        setTabLabel(tabInfo.tabId, "MyTabName");
        setTabIcon(tabInfo.tabId, "custom:custom90");
    });
}
```

(Icon id is coming from the [SLDS Icons](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/))

Comment: Does this change the browser's tab?

Comment: No the console tab as highlighted in my answer